# Getting information from an Intro Activity with custom made slide fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a list of recyclerview with checkboxes at a customized slide fragment and should have the information that which ones are checked at the main activity of the software. To clarify what slide fragment is: it is a custom fragment which is located in an intro activity. The intro activity is being called from the main activity of the software. I use the material-intro library for the intro part which is located in [here](https://github.com/heinrichreimer/material-intro).

What I have tried so far:

I tried to put an extra on the slide fragment's onDestroy function. The code goes like:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    List<Topic> list = adapter.getAdded();
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        result += list.get(i).getName() + "-";
    }
    returnIntent.putExtra("sourceList",result);

    getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    super.onStop();
}
```

The Intro activity's code is like this:
public class MainIntroActivity extends IntroActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setSkipEnabled(false);


    addSlide(new SimpleSlide.Builder()
            .background(R.color.Color_DarkGreen)
            .backgroundDark(R.color.Color_Black)
            .image(R.drawable.add_group)
            .title("Trial title")
            .description("Trial description")
            .build());//

    addSlide(new FragmentSlide.Builder()
    .background(R.color.Color_Blue)
    .backgroundDark(R.color.Color_DarkBlue)
    .fragment(SourceChooseFragment.newInstance())
    .build());


}}
```

I am creating the MainIntroActivity with the following code at the onCreate function of the main activity:

```
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

And I am expecting an information to retrieve with the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result = data.getStringExtra("sourceList");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

However I get this error:

```
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {net.fred.feedex/net.fred.feedex.activity.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Where did I go wrong and what is the correct way to send an information from the slide fragment to main activity?

Please let me know if this is a bad question and tell me how to improve it.

Have a nice day.

Edit 1: I noticed that onDestroy function was not being called so I have replaced it with the onStop function. It is being called now however the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You should try call finish() explicitly.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    List<Topic> list = adapter.getAdded();
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        result += list.get(i).getName() + "-";
    }
    returnIntent.putExtra("sourceList",result);

    getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    getActivity().finish()
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Unfortunately it diddn't help. However I updated the question. Can you take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The problem was the putExtra being called **BEFORE** the `setResult` function called. After a look at the library code, the setResult function was called a place somewhere odd. Used `goToSlide` function instead of `onStop` function which is the closest overridable function to the `setResult` function. The created overridden `goToSlide` function instead of `onStop` function is:

```
@Override
public boolean goToSlide(int position){

    if(position >= 3) {

        List<Topic> list = sourceChooseFragment.getAdded();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            result += list.get(i).getName() + "-";
        }
        intent.putExtra("sourceList", result);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();

    }
    return super.goToSlide(position);

}
```

TL;DR: The main issue was the putExtra function was calling before the setResult function. You just have to call putExtra before the setResult being called.